# Microsoft Excel if-then formula

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I am discounting new autos. G2 is the MSRP (sticker price) column. If the G2 is less than $30,000 then the discount would be G2 times `.003`, otherwise the discount is G2 times `.002`.

This discount is a subtracted amount. Here is what I was trying to write:

```
IF(G2<30000,-(G2*.003), -(G2*.004)))
```

Comment: sorry..  had my caps on because the print is so small for me to see

Answer (score 1):

This should be correct:

```
IF(G2<30000;-(G2*.003);-(G2*.004))
```

Comment: what if the result returned? have you tryed 0.003 instead of .003 ?

Answer (score 1):

`IF(G2<30000;-(G2*.003);-(G2*.004))` will only give you the discount amount. If you want the total price to include the discount:

`=IF(G2<3E+3,G2-(G2*0,003),G2-(G2*0.004))`

Kind of hard to see what you're asking for exactly.

Comment: No problem. If that was indeed the answer to your question please go ahead and click the blank checkmark by my answer so we can close out your question! Thanks.